# modify listing page in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, layout, directory

I'd like to change the layout of the listing page of a business directory so that it looks similar to this layout, http://pastebin.com/1aHenCCN, using the same Wordpress theme.

I will modify single-listing.php page (at minimum)

Could someone help me with this? I know that I may need to pay for this.

Answer (score 0):

listing page of all listing post type is    archive-listing.php ,
Single page of individual listing post type   is single-listing.php. So you need to modify archive-listing.php for to effect entire listing page.
Assume that listing is your post type  .

Comment: 1. Aren't there other files I would need to modify? For example, the style.css?

Comment: Yes, for changing the style you need to edit the style.css page .